# pdfSweep with rotated rectangle (itext7)

Tags: itext, itext7

i have the requirement to perform a redaction in itext7. We have several rectangles which have been selected by the user. Some of these have been rotated. I have not found the ability to rotate rectangles in itext7. Usually, how we draw "rotated" rectangles is to perform some mathematical operations on a "fake" rectangle we draw in the code, and then draw them either using a series of lines like so:

```
if (rect.mRotation > 0)
{
    r.Rotate(DegreeToRadian(rect.mRotation));
}

c.MoveTo(r.TopLeft.X, r.TopLeft.Y);

c.LineTo(r.TopRight.X, r.TopRight.Y);

c.LineTo(r.BottomRight.X, r.BottomRight.Y);

c.LineTo(r.BottomLeft.X, r.BottomLeft.Y);

c.LineTo(r.TopLeft.X, r.TopLeft.Y);

c.Stroke();
```

In the case of images, or something similar, we are unable to do the above. In this case we use an affinetransform to simulate the movement, which is applied to the image before it is added to the document. Both of the previous methods work perfectly.

Unfortunately for us, the pdfSweep tool only accepts (iText.Kernel.Geom) rectangles. We are looking for a way to be able to still pass an iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle which has had transforms applied (ie. a rectangle which has been rotated). We have tried setting the llx/urx values manually using the setBBox method, but this wont affect the rotation.

Does anyone know how we can go about redacting items over a given rectangular area which has been rotated?

Thanks

Comment: Could the rotation be whatsoever or are there any restrictions (for example, only 0/90/180/270 values) ?

Comment: Multiples of 90° would be trivial to resolve, so I would assume differently...

Comment: Yes, these are rectangles which are rotated at non-standard angles around the origin, 45 degrees for example making it (kind of) like a diamond if you can visualize that.

Comment: @Jingo unfortunately pdfSweep was indeed designed only for non-rotated rectangle areas redaction.

The only solution which comes to my mind is as follows: use a number of non-rotated rectangles which cover the rotated area you want to redact